# Water of cracked Kli

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing

Recalling a shiur on netilat yadayim, the speaker said that one is not allowed to do so if the kli of choice is leaking. You have to get another kli or otherwise go about washing differently.

If this is true - and I would love to know where to go to find this - what happens to the water of the pasul kli? Can it be transferred to the more qualified vessel or does the water lose the opportunity for the mitzvah but could be used to water a plant or something?